# Can't login to developer org. How to contact Salesforce support?

Tags: login, support

I have couple of issues login to my developer orgs.

1. I tried to reset the password. But once the reset link is clicked,
   it says "Your reset link expired after 24 hours or has already been
   used."
2. I switched to lightning experience. But now i cannot login to
   the account. It keep refreshing the page. Neither I cannot switch
   back to Classic again. I tried different browsers, cleared cache and
   everything I possibly can. But no luck as of yet.

I tried to submit a case from Help centre by login in as another developer org. But I'm not allowed to do so. Can someone please guide me how to do this?

Comment: have you try to change the password. Or set new one password which is unique not Old.

Comment: You can email support@salesforce.com for further assistance. They can help you there even if you cannot log in. If you have a partner portal login, you can request help there. Mostly you'll need to request escalation until you get help. It's not impossible, it's just really hard to get help.

Comment: They no longer accept emails sends to support@salesforce.com. Instead they asks to submit a case, which can not be done using developer org :(